# changing date formats to YYMMDD8. in SAS for date calculations

Tags: date, format, sas

I've got a date variable in my dataset(currently numeric) that has three types of dates:

1. just the year (yyyy)
2. year/month (yyyymm)
3. year/month/date (yyyymmdd)

I'm trying to convert the ones with just the year to January 1st, and convert the ones with year/month to the first of the month so that I can subtract the dates from another date variable in my dataset that has all the dates in yymmdd8 format (same as #3). I tried this in the data step and it's not working:

```
if length(Date)=4 then DateF=mdy(1,1,substr(Date,1,4));  
if length(Date)=6 then DateF=mdy(substr(Date,5,2),1,substr(Date,1,4));  
if length(Date)=8 then DateF=mdy(substr(Date,5,2),substr(Date,7,2),substr(Date,1,4));  
Date2=input(put(DateF,8.),YYMMDD8.);  
format Date2 YYMMDD8.;
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong with my code? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the variable is numeric?  I don't think a numeric var can display with different formats.

Comment: that's what it shows up as on proc contents. even if not i think input(put(variable)) can change the variable to numeric. should i try using the character variable instead?

Comment: Oh I understand now... there's no `/` character - just the numeric characters...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So to debug your code you can first try printing some of your assumptions to the screen.  I'd start by printing the result of your `if` statement...

```
data blah;

  format date best.;

  input date; 

  test1 = length(date);
  put test1=;

datalines;
  2014
  201408
  20140829
;
run;
```

This gives:

```
test1=12
test1=12
test1=12
```

Obviously not what we are expecting.  It looks like the numeric field is 12 characters long once it is automatically converted to a character variable, and when it is being converted, it is being padded with spaces at the front.  We can check this by replacing the put statement with this:

```
test2 = "*" || length(cats(date)) || "*";
put test2=;
```

This prints:

```
test2=*           4*
test2=*           6*
test2=*           8*
```

So what we need to do is to not rely on the automatic type conversion, as this will not only affect the `if` condition, but it will also affect the `substr()` functions.  Instead we will do it ourselves:

```
data blah;

  format date best.;


  input date; 

  tmp_date = cats(date);


  if length(tmp_Date)=4 then DateF=mdy(1,1,substr(tmp_Date,1,4));  
  if length(tmp_Date)=6 then DateF=mdy(substr(tmp_Date,5,2),1,substr(tmp_Date,1,4));  
  if length(tmp_Date)=8 then DateF=mdy(substr(tmp_Date,5,2),substr(tmp_Date,7,2),substr(tmp_Date,1,4));  

  format Datef YYMMDD8.;

datalines;
  2014
  201408
  20140829
;
run;
```

The `cats()` function will do the conversion for us, and trim the leading and trailing spaces! It's super useful... Anyway hopefully that explains what is going wrong and how you can debug your own code in future =).